# mysql_list_tables

Tags: php, kohana

I have a script in kohana which runs fine on php 5.2.11. I took out a line for mysql_select_tables using a mysql_query. When I put it on a php 5.3 server, I get the following errors:

Warning Message

An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.
system/libraries/drivers/Database/Mysql.php [483]:
mysql_data_seek() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
Stack Trace

system/libraries/drivers/Database/Mysql.php [483]:
mysql_data_seek( Resource id #39, mysql_fetch_array )
system/libraries/drivers/Database.php [558]:
Mysql_Result->seek( mysql_fetch_array )
application/views/right_menu.php [33]:
Database_Result->offsetGet( mysql_fetch_array )
system/libraries/Controller.php [74]:
include( application/views/right_menu.php )

I wonder if this is a seperate issue concerning php 5.2 vs. 5.3, or a result of replacing mysql_list_tables with a mysql_query("SHOW TABLES...")? It seems to be a problem with a string called mysql_fetch_array being sent to mysql_data_seek for the second parameter instead of a long, although this works in 5.2. Thanks.

Comment: It tells you right then and there that the second argument on line 483 in Mysql.php isn't what it should be. Fix that, or better yet: check whether a recent version of kohana hasn't fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function has been deprecated in 5.3 Please see the manual for other alternative [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php.)

According to php manual "**This function is deprecated. It is preferable to use mysql_query() to issue an SQL SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name] [LIKE 'pattern'] statement instead**"

Comment: Yes I saw that. I changed this 
$tables = mysql_list_tables($db);  
to
line $tables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $db;");

I run that change in PHP 5.2 and it works, while switching to php 5.3 throws the error.

One thing I noticed is this error mysql_data_seek() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given Stack Trace for mysql_data_seek( Resource id #39, mysql_fetch_array ).
Thanks.

Comment: @steve: There got to be some problem with mysql_data_seek() that you are using in the script . you might be passing wrong value to that function please check

Comment: "mysql_fetch_array" was being past to mysql_data_seek as the second parameter. Surprisingly this worked in php 5.2, but died in php 5.3.  I wonder if there is a debug setting? As a workaround I just manually set it to zero.